# How to use FileUploadInterceptor with struts2 convention plugin

Tags: upload, struts2, annotations, interceptor, convention

I'm trying to set the FileUploadInterceptor on an action by annotation :

```
@Namespace("/")
@ParentPackage("my-package")
@Result(name = "success", location = "/WEB-INF/jsp/result.jsp")
@InterceptorRef("fileUpload")
public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {

  private File upload;
  private String uploadContentType;
  private String uploadFileName;

  public void setUpload(File upload) {
    this.upload = upload;
  }
  public void setUploadContentType(String uploadContentType) {
    this.uploadContentType = uploadContentType;
  }
  public void setUploadFileName(String uploadFileName) {
    this.uploadFileName = uploadFileName;
  }
  public File getUpload() {
    return this.upload;
  }
  public String getUploadContentType() {
    return this.uploadContentType;
  }
  public String getUploadFileName() {
    return this.uploadFileName;
  }
  @Override
  @Action("doUpload")
  public String execute()
  {
    System.out.println("Upload ok : " + (this.upload != null));
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

My issue is that it works only if I don't set ANY interceptor on the action class. As soon as I set an interceptor, even FileUploadInterceptor like above, the attribute are not filled.

Basicaly, this works :

```
public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {...
```

But this DOESN'T work :

```
@InterceptorRefs({
  @InterceptorRef("fileUpload")
})
public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {...
```

or

```
@InterceptorRefs({
  @InterceptorRef("fileUpload"),
  @InterceptorRef("myOtherinterceptor")
})
public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {...
```

I found ! The solution is :

```
@InterceptorRefs({
  @InterceptorRef("fileUpload"),
  @InterceptorRef("basicStack")
})
public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set *any* interceptor, you must set *all* interceptors. Basically you're turning off all but the upload interceptor, which isn't what you want.

If you are going to manually configure interceptors, and need to refer to multiple interceptors, use the `@InterceptorRefs` "wrapper" annotation as per the [InterceptorRef docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-InterceptorRefannotation).

Comment: @Max No problem; if it resolves the problem, consider upvoting or [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)--but only if it helped!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But maybe I haven't been clear enough.

Basicaly, this works :

  public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {...

But this DOESN'T work :

  @InterceptorRefs({
    @InterceptorRef("fileUpload")
  })
  public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {...

or

  @InterceptorRefs({
    @InterceptorRef("fileUpload"),
    @InterceptorRef("myOtherinterceptor")
  })
  public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {...

Maybe there is a limitation of the use of the FileUploadInterceptor to configuration file and doesn't support the interceptor by annotation convention ?

Comment: I totally can't read that--if you have additional information, update your question. I still don't see any of the default S2 interceptors in there, though.

Comment: Sorry, it's the first time I post on this site. I updated the question.

What are the Default interceptor you are talking about ?

Comment: Yeeeesss I succeeded ! Actually, as you said, setting the FileUploadInterceptor manually needs the manual set of, at least, the "basicStack" interceptor as well. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Max Awesome, glad you worked it out--that interceptor thing gets a lot of people (including me sometimes ;)

Comment: If you are using the convention plugin, you should really take a look at the browser config plugin as well, at least during development. This makes it easy to see, on an action, by action basis, exactly how Struts sees your configuration. This tool has saved me hours when my expectations of how my app is wired is not how struts sees it.